# How to change values of selected cells?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to know how to, after selecting an amount of cells, use a button to apply its lines of code only on those selected cells.

i've tried selecting and just clicking on the button but didn't work.

if there's another option to allow me to do the same it's also a welcome idea

This is the code that i want to apply, but only on cells selected with my mouse, and not really pre-selected cells like the ones shown in the code.

```
If Range("h3").Value >= 0 Then
   Range("bk3").Value = True
Else
   Range("bk3").Value = False
End If

If Range("h3").Value >= 0 Then
    Range("j3").Value = Range("j3").Value & " | " & VarNUMCB
Else

End If

If Range("h3").Value >= 0 Then
   Range("l3").Value = Now
Else
End If
```

Comment: `Selection.Value = X`

Comment: If you are using vba; your macro should have `With Selection`

Comment: Please add your code to your question and format it. Basically, you would enclose your code within a `With Selection` and `End With`

Comment: @GMalc alright, i've put it on the question and thanks for the help

Comment: see my modification of your code.

Comment: I misunderstood what you were asking, Are you selecting a cell or a range of cells? can you give me an example?

Comment: Maybe I'm not explaining properly I'm not English sorry, it should work on both a single cell and a selection of cells. Any cell (s) as long as they are selected with your cursor .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
With Selection
    If Range("h3").Value >= 0 Then
        Range("bk3").Value = True
        Range("j3").Value = Range("j3").Value & " | " & VarNUMCB
        Range("l3").Value = Now
    Else
        Range("bk3").Value = False
    End If
End With
```

If you are selecting a cell in `column h`, then this code uses offset from the selected cell.

```
With Selection
    If .Value >= 0 Then
        .Offset(, 55).Value = True
        .Offset(, 2).Value = Range("j3").Value & " | " & "Yes"
        .Offset(, 3).Value = Now
    Else
        .Offset(, 55).Value = Falsee
    End If
End With
```

If you are selecting a range of cells in `column h` then you would have to put the above code within a `For Each Cell in Selection` loop

```
For Each cel in Selection
    If cel.Value >= 0 Then
        cel.Offset(, 55).Value = True
        cel.Offset(, 2).Value = Range("j3").Value & " | " & "Yes"
        cel.Offset(, 3).Value = Now
    Else
        cel.Offset(, 55).Value = False
    End If
Next cel
```

Comment: but the problem is i would want those lines to take effect on selected cells, not specifically the ones written. if i were to select A2 and A3 and click the button, those effects should happen on A2 and A3

Answer (score 1):

This will loop selected cells and alter them:

```
Set selectedRange = Application.Selection

For Each cell In selectedRange.Cells
   'do something with the cell, like:
   cell.value = cell.value + 1
Next cell
```